# Prob. 19, Sec. 2.3, in Herstein's TOPICS IN ALGEBRA, 2nd ed: Bracketing any $n$-tuple of elements in a set with an associative binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations, invariance, associativity

Here is Prob. 19, Sec. 2.3, in the book *Topics in Algebra* by I.N. Herstein, 2nd edition:

> If $S$ is a set closed under an associative operation, prove that no matter how you bracket $a_1a_2 \ldots a_n$, retaining the order of the elements, you get the same element in $S$ (e.g., $\left( a_1 \cdot a_2 \right) \codt \left( a_3 \cdot a_4 \right) = a_1 \cdot \left( a_2 \cdot \left( a_3 \cdot a_4 \right) \right)$; use induction on $n$).

My Attempt:

> Of course the assertion holds for $n = 1, 2, 3$. Suppose it holds for every $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 3$.
>
> Let $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots, a_n, a_{n+1}$ be any elements of set $S$.

How to proceed from here? How to prove *rigorously* that, no matter how we bracket $a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_n a_{n+1}$, retaining the order of the elements, we obtain the same element of $S$.

Comment: Start by choosing a bracketing of the expression $a_1a_2a_3....a_na_{n+1}$. Although if you want to do this *rigorously* then you'll need a rigorous definition of "bracketing".

Comment: @LeeMosher that's exactly what I'm unable to come up with, a _rigorous_ definition of "bracketing".

Comment: @Saaqib There are various syntactic representations we can use, e.g. we can use (binary) algebraic syntax (parse) trees, where each (interior) node is an operation, and each leave is an operand.

Comment: See my 12 September 2006 sci.math post [Combinatorics of associativity](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sci.math/MQRGtT7kVKE/TIIQ7C7O7vQJ).

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a *string* which is simply a finite sequence $w$.

Define an *association* of the string $w$ to be any string that is built by inserting characters "$($" and "$)$" into $w$ according to following rules. Let $N=\text{Length}(w)$.

- If $N \le 2$ then $w$ is the only association of $w$.
- If $N \ge 3$, first choose $n$ with $1 \le n \le N-1$, then decompose $w$ as a concatenation $w=uv$ where $\text{Length}(u)=n$ and $\text{Length}(v)=N-n$, and then:

  - If $n=1$, choose $v'$ to be any association of $v$, and then $u(v')$ is an association of $w$.
  - If $n=N-1$, choose $u'$ to be any association of $u$, and then $(u')v$ is an association of $w$.
  - If $2 \le n \le N-2$, choose $u'$ to be an association of $u$ and choose $v'$ to be an association of $v$, and then $(u')(v')$ is an association of $w$.

Now, as suggested, you should proceed by induction on the length of $w$, to prove that the outcome of multiplication is independent of the choice of association of $w$.